# getting jQuery error on strategery infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have implemented strategery2-3.5.3 in my magento project. I have set load more threshold property to 1000. due to this, instead of clicking the button, products will be load on scrolling only. But when i scrolled to see more products, it throws js error.

[image]

Comment: @Shiladitya its a strategery...

Comment: I don't think there's enough detail here to help you. Could you show your source code? Also, the error in the console should include the call stack. That would be helpful to see. In fact, you may be able to diagnose this yourself just by following the call stack.